# How to invoke AWS Lambda with Observable.bindNodeCallback(lambda.invoke)

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, rxjs, aws-lambda

I am trying to invoke a AWS Lambda function in a RxJS way:

```
invokeLambda(): Observable<string> {
  const lambda = new AWS.Lambda({region: environment.region, apiVersion: "2015-03-31"});
  const invoke$ = (functionName, payload, invocationType = "RequestResponse") => {
  return Observable.bindNodeCallback(lambda.invoke)();
};

return invoke$(environment.functionName, {}).map((result: InvocationResponse) => JSON.parse(<string>result.Payload));
```

}

however when I try:

```
this.myService.invokeLambda().subscribe(() => { dosomething(); }
```

I get the error:

```
page.html:5 ERROR TypeError: this.makeRequest is not a function
at svc.(anonymous function)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: seems context is not binded, have you tried `bindNodeCallback(lambda.invoke.bind(lambda))...`?

Comment: worked like a charme. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I recommend creating a facade for dispatching http requests to Amazon API Gateway that is a proxy to AWS Lambda. You can wrap the AWS SDK event handler in an observable. In the following example I am utilizing rxjs to search for an identity pool name and determine if the name exists within a list of Amazon Cognito Federated Identities Identity Pools within my AWS account. I integrated the Lambda function with AWS Step Functions to enhance rxjs "next" channel capabilities. Rxjs, AWS Lambda, and AWS Step Functions retry task state definitions allowed me to "continue" Amazon Cognito Federated Identities identity pool name existence search via pagination of the cognitoidentity.listIdentityPools names. Step Functions enables recursive execution of lambda functions when using rxjs. By returning the pagination token returned from the first execution of lambda function as a parameter to the next recursive execution of the lambda function via step function states. I.e.

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

  AWS.config.region = "...";

  AWS.config.apiVersions = {
    cognitoidentity: '2014-06-30'
  };

  var cognitoidentity = new AWS.CognitoIdentity();

  var params = {
    MaxResults: 1,
    get NextToken() {
      if (event.NextToken == null || undefined) {
        return null;
      } else {
        return event.NextToken;
      }
    }
  };

  var eventResult = {
    identityPoolName: '',
    identityPoolId: '',
    NextToken: '',
    NextState: '',
    error: '',
    errorReason: ''
  };

 function listIdentityPoolsObservable(params) {
   return Rx.Observable.create(observer => {

    cognitoidentity.listIdentityPools(params)
      .on('success', function(response) {
        observer.next(response.data);
      })
      .on('error', function(error, response) {
        observer.error(error);
      })
      .on('complete', function(response) {
        if (response.error) {
          observer.error(response.error)
        } else {
          observer.complete(response);
        }
      }).send();
    });
  };

  const source$ = listIdentityPoolsObservable(params)
    .share()
    .observeOn(Rx.Scheduler.asap);

  const identityPoolsSource$ = source$.map(x => {
    return x.IdentityPools;
  })
  .flatMap(x => {
    return x;
  })
  .filter( x => x.IdentityPoolName === event.identityPoolName)
  .map(x => {
    if (x.IdentityPoolName === event.identityPoolName) {
      var dataArr = [x.IdentityPoolName, x.IdentityPoolId];
      return dataArr;
    }
  })
  .defaultIfEmpty(false);

  const nextTokenSource$ = source$
    .filter(x => x.NextToken != null || undefined)
    .map(x => {
      if (x.NextToken != null || undefined) {
        return x.NextToken;  
      }
     })
     .defaultIfEmpty(false);

  var identityAndToken = Rx.Observable
    .forkJoin(identityPoolsSource$, nextTokenSource$)
    .subscribe(x => {
      //conditional statements...
      callback(null, eventResult);
    });

  function ExceptionExistence(eventResult) {
    this.name = eventResult.errorName;
    this.errorReason = eventResult.errorReason;
  };
  ExceptionExistence.prototype = new Error();

};
```